# MainWindowTitle is an empty string ("")

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

While executing my test cases throwing an error "Test Run deployment issue:

> Failed to get the file for deployment item '%TEST%\en' (output
>   directory 'en'): System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   'C:\output\Debug\bin\en'.

When I debug the code I got to know the main window title of server is getting empty. My execution will be on Internet explorer but IExplorer Server is not starting.

Can anybody help me out from this problem.
Here, my process code

```
public static Process GetSingleProcessWithMainWindowTitle(string name, IEnumerable<Process> exceptList )
{
    var processes = GetProcesses(name, exceptList);
    var process = processes.Single(proc => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(proc.MainWindowTitle));
    return process;
}
```

Comment: So when title of your main window is empty, you need to do something? is that correct? Or you need to watch for title of some other application is became empty?

Comment: Yes I need to read window name

Comment: Form caption is in  `this.Text` property. And you can catch it with `this.TextChanged` event